# Firebase iphone simulator pair to mac is not working and returning null Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Why Firebase.Auth.Auth.DefaultInstance is returning Null?

I'm using xamarin iphone simulator by pair to mac

First, When I tried to sign in using my Apple ID, it returns a warning after selecting my team "There are no current IOS devices on this team matching the provided device IDs"

Second, When I set custom entitlements manually, it returns compile error "Could not find any available provisioning profiles for TravelRecordApp.iOS on iOS"

Third, When I am not set custom entitlements, it returns null when calling Firebase.Auth.Auth.DefaultInstance
to create user

await Firebase.Auth.Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserAsync(email, password);

my steps:
Add "Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth" NuGet package to iOS project
Import "GoogleService-Info.plist" and set the building action to "BundleResource"
Make sure that my bundle identifier is identical to the bundle identifier inside "GoogleService-Info.plist"
Add the next line of code in the AppDelegate.cs FinishedLaunching before LoadApplication:
Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

Note I am using visual studio 2022

Please advice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Mac up to date, with Xcode up to date and Visual Studio for Mac installed?

You need an up to date setup on the Mac to use the simulator with Pair To Mac in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: It may be the reason, as on windows is installed vs2022 and on mac is installed vs2019 and Xcode 13.2, I will request to update for the latest version, Thank you.